# how to reconstruct an phase information from the magnitude spectrogram

Tags: fourier-transform, phase, spectrogram

I need to recreate the phase of a spectogram of magnitude and when inverse fourier, that the sound is understandable and not pure noise

Observe these softwares

https://photosounder.com/

http://warmplace.ru/soft/ans/

they can partially recreate the audio from the magnitude spectrogram.

What algorithms do you use to create the phase information, so that it doesn't sound like noise?

try to randomize the containers with the -pi pi phase and then when inverse fourier you hear pure noise.
How do these programs rebuild phase information?